# How would one write conditional injection of the dependency?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

please consider following situation: there is class `SampleViewModel`, which is dependent on classes `FileDataReader` and `TransmissionManager` (`TransmissionManager` is also dependent on `FileDataReader`), where `FileDataReader` can be in two states - valid or invalid. Invalid state means that this instance cannot be used (it reads data from file, if this file is corrputed state is changed to invalid). Without `FileDataReader`, instances of `SampleViewModel` and `TransmissionManager` are also useless, because this dependency is crucial. How should I write proper code that wires this three classes together?

```
public class FileDataReader
{
    public bool IsDataValid { get; private set; }

    public FileDataReader()
    {
        IsDataValid = ReadAllData();
    }

    private bool ReadAllData()
    {
        // ...
    }
}

public class TransmissionManager
{
    private readonly FileDataReader _reader;

    public TransmissionManager(FileDataReader reader)
    {
        _reader = reader;
    }

    // all methods need reader to be valid in order to work
}

public class SampleViewModel
{
    private readonly FileDataReader _dependency;

    public SampleViewModel(FileDataReader dependency, TransmissionManager manager)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;

        if (_dependency.IsDataValid)
        {
            // crucial code that operates on manager instance
        }
    }
}
```

Please note, that even if data is invalid, I still need to show the main window and write proper message for user. Now I see two options:

1. In composition root I register class `FileDataReader`, resolve its instance, check if its valid and if it is, register `TransmissionManager` and then `SampleViewModel`. Then application can proceed in normal state. If it's not valid, I register another view model that handles error message etc.
2. I register all classes without any checking, and in all classes that depend on `FileDataManager` - if it's invalid - I throw `InvalidArgumentException`. The question is, where to catch it, bearing in mind, that I have to show the error to the user.

Please help me with this. Maybe you have other options?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I updated class names and added another dependency, which is the one that complicates the situation.

Comment: instead of using `A` and `B` should have used Proper class name, could have gave better understanding of the problem, question is quite unclear!

Comment: throw an exception if dependency is not valid!

Answer (score 1):

Services in your application should mainly be stateless. The fact that your `FileDataReader` can be in a valid or invalid state means that there's something wrong with your design.

Here are some other options:

1. Check the validity of the system during startup and show the user a warning if the read file is correct.
2. Wrap the `FileDataReader` with a decorator that catches any exception that's coming from the `FileDataReader` and shows a clear message to the user explaining that the 'choosen' file is corrupt.

Comment: Why do you say that having stateful service is a bad design? I've seen a lot of classes that throw exceptions when accessing invalid properties. I didn't want to bubble up each exception, but instead seting state to invalid, meaning that reading class's properties can result in unexpected behaviour. Correct me if I'm wrong, but you suggest throwing exception every time I want access invalid property, right? I want to avoid this and fail early, so other classes that are deeper in the hierarchy do not have to worry if `Reader` is valid or not.

Comment: If you look at the `SampleViewModel` constructor, you can see that `TransmissionManager` uses stateful dependency. I wanted to avoid injecting `TransmissionManager` instance if the `FileDataReader` is invalid. I thought of workaround though - I inject only `FileDataReader` instance, check for its correctness and then use ServiceLocator (yikes! anti-pattern!) to retrieve `TransmissionManager`, which will work without problems then.

Comment: @MarekKowalczyk: I can't really comment on that, because I know too little about your design and you didn't show enough information to give some good specific alternatives. But in general, you should try to design your system with stateless services.

Comment: I think the code I supplied gives an idea about the design. When application starts it needs to check if configuration data is loaded and valid. If it is, `TransmissionManager` is asked to start remote transmision. `SampleViewModel` orchestrates this process. `TransmissionManager` in its constructor uses properties retrieved from `FileDataManager`, so I want to delay its creation, until Im 100% sure that `FileDataManager` is valid, so it won't raise any exception elsewhere.